# Encountered end tag "li" with no matching start tag error when putting li inside if statement

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i am using asp.net MVC 5 and Visual studio 2013

and working on Razor view

the view is working fine without if statement around the < li > start

if i enclosed any < li > start, with an if condition statement i get this error

Parser Error Message: Encountered end tag "li" with no matching start tag.  Are your start/end tags properly balanced?

```
@using TheodorHR_App.Models
<div id="tree_CadreGroupLevel" class="tree-demo">
    <ul>
        @{
            TheodorHrEntities db = new TheodorHrEntities();
            var nodes = db.Cadres.ToList();
            foreach (var node in nodes)
            {
                Cadre root = new Cadre();
                root.Id = node.Id;
                if (@Model.RuleElementCadres.Select(e => e).Where(e => e.Cadre == node.Id).Count() > 0)
                {
                    <text>
                        <li id="Cnode_@node.Id" data-jstree='{ "selected" : true }'>
                    </text>
                }
                else
                {
                    <text>
                    <li id="Cnode_@node.Id">
                    </text>
                }

                        <a href="#">@node.Name</a>
                        <ul>
                            @{
                                var nodes1 = db.JobGroups.Where(jg => jg.CadreId == @node.Id).ToList();
                                foreach (var node1 in nodes1)
                                {
                                    Cadre root1 = new Cadre();
                                    root1.Id = node1.Id;
                                    <li id="Gnode_@node1.Id">
                                        <a href="#">@node1.Name</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            @{
                                                var nodes2 = db.JobGroupJobLevels.Where(jl => jl.JobGroup == @node1.Id).ToList();
                                                foreach (var node2 in nodes2)
                                                {
                                                    Cadre root2 = new Cadre();
                                                    root2.Id = node2.Id;
                                                    <li id="Lnode_@node2.Id">
                                                        <a href="#">@node2.JobLevel1.Name</a>
                                                        <ul></ul>
                                                    </li>
                                                }
                                            }
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                }
                            }
                        </ul>
                </li>
            }
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

- Update after first answer 
  doesn't work
  [image]

Razor understand it as c# and tried to enclose it with double quotes doesn't work because the literal contains already doubles quotes then tried to replace " with \" this doesnt work because it doesn't give a meaning to the js Tree i am building

Comment: Syntactical error, Try resolving it like `"data-jstree=\"{ 'selected' : true }\""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the solution elsewhere

i think there is an issue on adding server side code inside html tags like this

< li /* adding server code here leads in many inconvenient issues */ >

i found the solution by adding @:< / li > at the end of the li instead of just < / li >

Answer (score 0):

Oh I Forgot to put the quotes around the attribute.

I think using a conditional operator might solve the issue.

```
@using TheodorHR_App.Models
<div id="tree_CadreGroupLevel" class="tree-demo">
<ul>
    @{
        TheodorHrEntities db = new TheodorHrEntities();
        var nodes = db.Cadres.ToList();
        foreach (var node in nodes)
        {
            Cadre root = new Cadre();
            root.Id = node.Id;

                    <li id="Cnode_@node.Id" @(Model.RuleElementCadres.Select(e => e).Where(e => e.Cadre == node.Id).Count() > 0 ?  "data-jstree='{ 'selected' : true }'" : "") >


                    <a href="#">@node.Name</a>
                    <ul>
                        @{
                            var nodes1 = db.JobGroups.Where(jg => jg.CadreId == @node.Id).ToList();
                            foreach (var node1 in nodes1)
                            {
                                Cadre root1 = new Cadre();
                                root1.Id = node1.Id;
                                <li id="Gnode_@node1.Id">
                                    <a href="#">@node1.Name</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        @{
                                            var nodes2 = db.JobGroupJobLevels.Where(jl => jl.JobGroup == @node1.Id).ToList();
                                            foreach (var node2 in nodes2)
                                            {
                                                Cadre root2 = new Cadre();
                                                root2.Id = node2.Id;
                                                <li id="Lnode_@node2.Id">
                                                    <a href="#">@node2.JobLevel1.Name</a>
                                                    <ul></ul>
                                                </li>
                                            }
                                        }
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            }
                        }
                    </ul>
            </li>
        }
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: * Update with a screenshot above as a update to the original post as i cant post a photo in this comment ..  
doesn't work,


Razor understand it as c# and tried to enclose it with double quotes doesn't work because the literal contains already doubles quotes then tried to replace " with \" this doesnt work because it doesn't give a meaning to the js Tree i am building

Comment: I Forgot to put the quotes in the html attribute
Try this.
`code`<li id="Cnode_@node.Id" @(Model.RuleElementCadres.Select(e => e).Where(e => e.Cadre == node.Id).Count() > 0 ?  "data-jstree='{ 'selected' : true }'" : "") >

Comment: doesn't work i think there is an issue on adding server side code inside html tags ... but i found the solution elsewhere by adding @:< / li > at the end of the li instead of just < / li > ... thanks for your care